# Need help in transforming spark dataframe using dataframe pivot

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pivot

I have below spark dataframe and i need to pivot only(`Histogram.ratio` and `Histogram.abs`) in `name` column.

```
 Instance   name               Abs_value    Ratio_value  
 A37        Histogram.ratio.1    0.70         Null           
 A37        Histogram.abs.1      20           Null           
 A37        Histogram.ratio.2    0.50         Null           
 A37        Histogram.abs.2      15           Null           
 A37        Mean                 20           Null           
 A37        Min                  3            Null           
 A37        Missingratio         Null           3
```

Expected output:

```
 Instance   name               Abs_value    Ratio_value  
 A37        Histogram.1          20           0.70                  
 A37        Histogram.2          15           0.50           
 A37        Mean                 20           Null           
 A37        Min                  3            Null           
 A37        Missingratio         Null           3
```

I tried using dataframe.pivot with filtering `name` column but not working as expected. Need help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do some preprocessing to (1) create a new column `type` based on `if Ratio_value is NULL` and `if name contains .ratio.`, (2) remove `\.(ratio|abs)\.` from `name` column, (3) use coalesce function to combine `Abs_value` and `Ratio_value` columns, and then do the regular pivot processing:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{regexp_replace,coalesce,expr,first}

val df_new = (df.select(
      'Instance,
      regexp_replace('name, "[.](?:ratio|abs)[.]", ".") as 'name,
      coalesce('Ratio_value, 'Abs_value) as 'value,
      expr("IF(instr(name,'.ratio.') > 0 OR Ratio_value is NOT NULL, 'Ratio_value','Abs_value') as type")
  )
  .groupBy('Instance, 'name)
  .pivot('type, Seq("Abs_value","Ratio_value"))
  .agg(first('value)))

df_new.show
+--------+------------+---------+-----------+                                   
|Instance|        name|Abs_value|Ratio_value|
+--------+------------+---------+-----------+
|     A37| Histogram.1|       20|       0.70|
|     A37|         Min|        3|       null|
|     A37|        Mean|       20|       null|
|     A37| Histogram.2|       15|       0.50|
|     A37|Missingratio|     null|          3|
+--------+------------+---------+-----------+
```

**Method-2:** If the number of rows containing `.ratio.` or `.abs.` is small, handle them separately with pivot and then union the rest of Rows.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{regexp_replace,when,first}

val cond = 'name.contains(".ratio.") || 'name.contains(".abs.")
val df1 = (df.filter(cond)
    .select(
      'Instance, 
      regexp_replace('name, "[.](ratio|abs)[.]", ".") as 'name, 
      when('name.contains(".ratio."),"Ratio_value").otherwise("Abs_value") as 'type,
      'Abs_value as 'value)
    .groupBy('Instance, 'name)
    .pivot('type, Seq("Abs_value", "Ratio_value"))
    .agg(first('value)))

val df_new = df.filter(!cond).union(df1)
```

**Method-3:** split the original dataframe into two based on if the sub-string `.ratio.` exists in the name, then do a full outer join:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{regexp_replace,coalesce}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

val adjust_name = (c:Column) => regexp_replace(c, "[.](ratio|abs)[.]", ".") 
val cond = 'name.contains(".ratio.")

val df1 = df.filter(!cond).withColumn("name", adjust_name('name))
+--------+------------+---------+-----------+
|Instance|        name|Abs_value|Ratio_value|
+--------+------------+---------+-----------+
|     A37| Histogram.1|       20|       null|
|     A37| Histogram.2|       15|       null|
|     A37|        Mean|       20|       null|
|     A37|         Min|        3|       null|
|     A37|Missingratio|     null|          3|
+--------+------------+---------+-----------+

val df2 = df.filter(cond).select('Instance, adjust_name('name) as 'name, 'Abs_value as 'Ratio_value1)
+--------+-----------+------------+
|Instance|       name|Ratio_value1|
+--------+-----------+------------+
|     A37|Histogram.1|        0.70|
|     A37|Histogram.2|        0.50|
+--------+-----------+------------+

val df_new = (df1.join(df2, Seq("Instance","name"),"full")
    .select('Instance, 'name, 'Abs_value, coalesce('Ratio_value, 'Ratio_value1) as 'Ratio_value))
```